# Unable to update data using SQL*Plus command in shell script

Tags: database, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a select query embedded in to my SQL*Plus command as shown below.

```
ret_val=`sqlplus -S "$user/$pwd@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=$host)(PORT=$port)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID=$sid)))"<<EOF>temp.dat                     
              WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 2;
              WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 3;
              select * from my_table;
              commit;
              exit;
              EOF`
```

It works all fine and promptly writes the result set of the select query in to the temp.dat file. But the below command with an update query doesn't seem to work. The screen is hung up waiting for me to input rather than updating the database.

```
ret_val=`sqlplus -S "$user/$pwd@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=$host)(PORT=$port)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID=$sid)))"<<EOF>temp.dat                     
              WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 2;
              WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 3;
              update my_table set my_column = 123 where id = 1;
              commit;
              exit;
              EOF`
```

When i terminate it by pressing Ctrl+C and open up the temp.dat file I see an error message as shown below.

```
ERROR at line 1: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
```

I am working on K Shell with Oracle database. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: are you sure it's hung and not just busy processing the update command? if you're testing your script, it's possible you left the UPDATE going w/o a commit and have a LOCK on my_table

Comment: Yup. It isn't hung up coz of the lock. If you look closely I have a commit command inside the SQL plus command itself.

Comment: yeah, but that commit doesn't run until the update finishes and if you stopped the script before the udpate finished...i'm assuming you checked for locks/wait events

Comment: Got it. The culprit is a colleague of mine who had updated the very same record on SQL Developer but hadn't committed it. It took me a couple of hours to actually find out the person. Once he committed his changes my script ran just fine.

Comment: I somehow assumed the command would time out after a few seconds which didn't happen. Is there a way I can force it to time out after may be a minute or so?

Comment: DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/ddl-lock-timeout-11gr1

Comment: Yup. That works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you're termination update statement in the middle of execution. Here you've used **"sqlplus -s"** where **-s** means silent mode, in this mode, you can not see the detail activity of sqlplus command.

Read the error: `ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation`,  this error message itself telling "requested cancel" after `Ctrl+C` as you pressed.

Try Again after removing -s option:

```
ret_val=`sqlplus "$user/$pwd@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=$host)(PORT=$port)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID=$sid)))"<<EOF>temp.dat                     
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 2;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 3;
update my_table set my_column = 123 where id = 1;
commit;
exit;
EOF`
```

I hope it this help, Thanks!